# Are certain simple Lie groups linear algebraic groups?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Assume you have an almost connected simple Lie group G with trivial center. (In particular excluding non-algebraic examples such as the universal cover of SL_2(R).)

Such a group should automatically be an algebraic group over the reals resp. the complex numbers.

Is this true and why?

Can we in addition conclude (EDIT: under a good choice of the field and possibly additional assumptions?)  that G is absolutely almost simple as an algebraic group?

EDIT: Asking this I do not want to regard a complex Lie group as a real algebraic group.

Comment: I guess that by "be an alg. group over reals" you mean "is topologically isomorphic to the group of real points of a real algebraic group" (or equivalently, to avoid algebraic groups language, is topologically isomorphic to a Zariski closed subgroup in some $SL_n(\mathbf{R})$). Then $PSL(2,\mathbf{R})$ is a counterexample, although it has index two in $PGL(2,\mathbf{R})$ [the notation is dangerous: if you define $PSL_2(\mathbf{R})$ as the group of real points of the group scheme $PSL_2$, you get $PGL_2(\mathbf{R})$]. 

Comment: Also look at $PGL(2,{\bf C})$ viewed as a real Lie group. The complexification of its Lie algebra is not simple.

Comment: @Yves Cornulier: can we resolve this problem in general by passing to a finite cover of the group under consideration? Hence maybe editing the question such that we ask for some finite cover of the Lie group to be always algebraic? 

Comment: @Wildberd: So you say that the additional conclusion does not hold, yes? 

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6079/classification-of-compact-lie-groups/16269#16269 ?

Comment: @Petra: for many purposes, to have $G$ as a Zariski dense, open (for the ordinary topology) subgroup of finite index in the group of real points of some algebraic groups, is enough: you can invoke Zariski topology, etc. Otherwise if $G$ is connected for the ordinary topology, it indeed admits a finite covering, that consists of the real points of the simply connected covering (in the algebraic sense) of the corresponding algebraic group.

Comment: Another problem: the connected component of identity in a non-compact orthogonal group $O(p,q)$ has index 4, whereas the algebraic connected component $SO(p,q)$ has index 2.

Comment: @Victor: it's not *another* problem: it *is* the problem I address with $PGL_2$: it is connected so $PGL_2(\mathbf{R})$ is connected in the Zariski topology but is not connected for the ordinary topology. 

Comment: You are right, $PGL_2(R)$ is $SO(1,2).$ I guess the reason (connectedness in Zariski vs real topology) was not immediately clear from your first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes for complex Lie groups, and follows from the classification. (Root data are in fact defined over $\mathbb{Z}$: a complex semisimple group has not only an underlying algebraic, but even an arithmetic structure). For a more direct explanation, see Theorem 6.3 in the book "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras III" by Onischik-Vinberg: any connected complex Lie group satisfying $G = [G,G]$ and admitting a faithful linear representation (which for semisimple groups is automatic), has a unique underlying complex algebraic structure.

For real Lie groups this is not *quite* true, as noted above.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I'll have a look at it. 
Do you know how to make a precise statement for the real case? 

Comment: @Petra: You can find the same theorem in the book "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" by Onishchik and Vinberg, Section 3.3.4, Theorem 5 on page 125.

Comment: @Petra: If $G$ is an adjoint connected semisimple $\mathbf{R}$-group and $G^{\rm{sc}} \rightarrow G$ is the simply connected central cover in the algebraic sense then $G^{\rm{sc}}(\mathbf{R})$ is connected (and a finite cover of the centerless $G(\mathbf{R})^0$). If we let $H$ vary through the connected semisimple $\mathbf{R}$-groups that are simply connected in the algebraic sense then $H \rightsquigarrow H(\mathbf{R})$ is *fully faithful* from the category of such $H$ to the category of (connected) Lie groups. Is this what you want to understand (or maybe Borovoi's reference explains it)?