# Para-Complexification of Lie Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a real Lie group.  Then the  complexification $G_\mathbb{C}$ of $G$ is the unique complex Lie group equipped with a map $φ:G\to G_\mathbb{C}$ such that any map $G\to H$ where $H$ is a 
complex Lie group, extends to a holomorphic map $G_\mathbb{C}\to H$.  If $\mathfrak{g}$ and 
$\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}$ are the respective Lie algebras, $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}≅\mathfrak{g}⊗_R \mathbb{C}$.

The algebra of para-complex numbers is defined by
$C = \mathbb{R} + e\mathbb{R}$ , $e^2=1$. The Para-complex structure in a vector space$ V $ is:

$K : V \to V$;   with $K^2 = 1$. such that
$V = V^+ + V^-$ ;$ dimV^+ = dimV^-$. 
Para-complexication of $(V; K)$ is $V^\mathbb{C}
:= V\otimes C$.

So, In a same method, We can define para-complexification of Lie Groups .

So, My questions are 1) can we say the para-complexification of a lie group is equal to  its complexification ? . If not, the paracomplexification of a lie group is unique?. For instance what is the paracomplexification of $U(n)$,

Also we know that the complexification of $U(n)$ is $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$

Comment: What would it mean for a Lie group $G$ to admit a para-complex structure? Is there a notion of integrability analogous to that required for an almost complex structure to be complex?

Comment: You can find here http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/15773/1/RockyCFG.PDF .

Comment: I think the paracomplexification is $G \times G$.

Comment: There are several undefined steps here, since you haven't defined what a paracomplex manifold is, or what the analogue of holomorphic map should be.  However, in the linear category, it is clear that the paracomplexification of the Lie algebra is given by taking the direct sum of two copies.  When your Lie group is compact (e.g., for your example of $U(n)$), you can use Chevalley's theorem to transport the question into the setting of anisotropic reductive groups: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6079/classification-of-compact-lie-groups/16269#16269

Comment: An almost-paracomplex manifold is a smooth real even-dimensional manifold with a paracomplex structure (an endomorphism defined as above) defined on its tangent bundle, and morphisms are smooth maps preserving it. I can't remember if there is a notion of integrability.

Comment: The above definition of $complexification$ is not the standard notion. Typically, for a real lie group $G$ one complexifies with respect to a maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$. The lie algebra of the complexification $G_{K,\mathbb{C}}=G_\mathbb{C}$ will be identified with $\mathfrak{k} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$. Without assuming that $G$ is reductive I am skeptical that a `complexification" in the sense of the above mapping property exists or is unique up to biholomorphism.

Comment: The above definition of paracomplexity is bizarre. The linear isomorphism $K:V\to V$ already splits over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $V=V_+ \oplus V_-$. So what is the meaning of saying ``the paracomplexification of $(V,K)$ is $V\otimes \mathbb{C}$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}[e]$ by $A \mapsto A-Ae$, and call the image $\mathfrak{g}^{(1,0)}$. 
Include $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}[e]$ by $A \mapsto A+Ae$, and call the image $\mathfrak{g}^{(0,1)}$. 
Linear algebra: we can write every element of $\mathfrak{g}[e]$ uniquely as a sum of a $(1,0)$ with a $(0,1)$, so that $\mathfrak{g}[e]=\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{g}$. To be precise, $A+Be=P+Q$ where $P=(A-B)/2-(A-B)e/2$ and $Q=(A+B)/2+(A+B)e/2$.
We can also write the elements of the form $A+0e$ as $\mathfrak{g}[e]_{\mathbb{R}}$, the real points.
If $G$ is a Lie group, then let $G[e]=G \times G$, so that we can say that $G[e]$ has Lie algebra canonically isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}[e]$, so that the induced Lie algebra morphism $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}[e]$ is $A \mapsto A+0e$. A paracomplex Lie group is a Lie group with biinvariant splitting of its tangent bundle, $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{h}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{h}_2$, and isomorphism of the two Lie algebras $\mathfrak{h}_1=\mathfrak{h}_2$, i.e. biinvariant isomorphism $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{g}[e]$ for some Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. If $\phi \colon G \to H$ is a morphism of Lie groups, with $H$ a paracomplex Lie group, then we define the associated Lie algebra morphism $\phi \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$, and extend it uniquely to a Lie algebra morphism $\phi \colon \mathfrak{g}[e] \to \mathfrak{h}$ by $e$-linearity. I will have to think about the group morphisms. But it should be easy for morphisms $\phi \colon G \to H[e]$: you should extend to $\phi \colon G[e] \to H[e]$ by writing the original morphism as $\phi \colon G \to H \times H$, say $\phi=\left(\phi_1,\phi_2\right)$ and letting $\phi\left(g_1,g_2\right)=\left(\phi_1\left(g_1\right),\phi_2\left(g_2\right)\right)$.

Comment: This is likely to show that the paracomplexification of a *simply connected* Lie group $G$ is the diagonal embedding of $G$ into $G\times G$. In general, if $G$ is a connected Lie group, say $G=\tilde{G}/Z$ with $\tilde{G}$ its universal covering, doesn't it follow that the complexification is the diagonal embedding of $G$ into  $(\tilde{G}\times\tilde{G})/Z$, where $Z$ is diagonally embedded?